# Lag in sensor reading when Arduino Powered with 12V adaptor

Tags: arduino-nano, sensors, power

So I am trying to power an arduino to measure water flow. It works all fine and dandy when I am powering it with laptop, but when I directly power it with 12V 1.5A adaptor the readings take a second to come to the LCD even though the pump starts running. Also when they come, I can see that sometimes it hangs. Why is that?

Before taking the readings I am switching on a motor which is also directly powered by the adaptor just like the arduino.

Below is a block diagram.

[image]

Would adding a voltage regulator that steps down 12V to 9v between arduino and adaptor help?

Comment: Please show your code and your actual wiring, not only a course scheme.

Comment: @chrisl does code matter if it works fine on power from laptop? Its just a command to switch on the relay (which switches on the pump) switch and next command starts printing the sensor values on LCD...

Comment: Can you check the voltage of your power supply with a voltmeter? Does it drop when the motor is turned on?

Comment: @EdgarBonet yup, true, just checked, the voltage to vin drops by nearly one volt even though I am powering it through LM7812 regulator module. The main power source voltage falls by almost two volts.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I am using this regulator (https://www.electronicscomp.com/lm7812-12v-dc-ac-three-terminal-voltage-regulator-power-module?gclid=CjwKCAjwtKmaBhBMEiwAyINuwPN5G4qe8VA7Ph4SIXA2q-S0DIiZIf6m9JAuTOHBV2SMhl5Y-iIcbhoCQlQQAvD_BwE), even then voltage is not constant

Comment: Thanks for adding a schematic.  I gave you an up vote for that.  Because the relay is not actually in the schematic (just the relay socket) I can not tell if it is a only a bare relay (then it too likely needs a reversed bias diode) or if it a module which already contains a diode or a diode and a driver circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your power supply is actually advertised at 1.2 Amps.  It's assumed you are powering the Arduino, the Relay, the Water Valve Solenoid and the Water-Pump-Motor all w/the same 1.2A power supply.  It is within reason that the sum of all those loads exceeds your power supply's capabilities.

> It works all fine and dandy when I am powering it with laptop ...

It is assumed you were only powering the Arduino with the laptop.  Providing the Arudino with an independent power source is a common solution to this type of problem.  Obtaining a larger power supply (more Amps) is another possible solution.

Why does it eventually work?

Motors require more Amps when under a physical load.  If the water is stationary, the motor will have to "get it moving" requiring more current. The term "locked motor current" is used [here in this article](https://www.jadelearning.com/blog/understanding-motor-starting-inrush-currents-nec-article-430-52/).

Also, inductor loads require more Amps when ever the voltage potential is suddenly changed.  The motor and relay are likely both seen as inductive loads.  This is referred to as [inrush current](https://www.sunpower-uk.com/glossary/what-is-inrush-current/).

Both of these can be assumed transitory.  Once the motor is moving and after the potential across the inductive loads are closer to zero, the initial current demand will subside and the power supply may then be capable of sustaining the constant voltage needed by the Arduino's processor.

Alternate solution:

Obtaining a larger power supply is likely the better solution.  Another option involves filtering the power only for the Arduino.  This option is discussed [in this thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/noise-filter-for-uno-power-supply/228542) on forum.arduino.cc where a diode and capacitor are used to somewhat isolate the power for the motor, relay and solenoid from the Arduino.

Comment: Ok, Ok. My adaptor is 1.5A, so I guess I should go for 2A? And also replace my LM7812 with a more amps module? Can you recommend something? I must use only a single power source, I can't use two power sources, so will have to look for a solution around this...

Comment: and your answer also explains the voltage drop which I mentioned in my comment on my question? I'm an amateur enthusiast, so might not understand too technical english...

Comment: Relay is powered by arduino, but yeah, there's a solenoid valve in there also on the power adaptor sucking a lot of current probably

Comment: If you're constrained to only one power supply then likely you need, as you said, a power supply rated for more amps.  I usually add up the maximum required currents and find a power supply with double the capacity.  There are ways around this.  But they require more knowledge and testing.  They are usually reserved for situations that are cost sensitive.  Like isolating the power path to the Arduino with a diode and a capacitor. Or somehow attenuating the inrush current to the motor.  Something along the lines of a [soft start motor device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_soft_starter).

Comment: Wait, you have a solenoid valve as well?  If the water is under pressure, why use a pump at all?  And if not under pressure, why use the solenoid valve?

Comment: Water is not under pressure. I thought maybe the pump could lead to leakage of flow, so to stop flow absolutely when I wanted I added a valve.

Comment: I would test it once without the valve, see if the valve is actually serving a purpose.

Comment: And about that solution, situations always like to be cost sensitive. So I can try putting a diode between the Vin pin and the +ve terminal? And what value capacitor can I use? Since LM7812 regulator module already has two capacitors, would adding another in the path help?

Comment: If this is a 1 time project, I would try a dependable solution by obtaining a higher capacity power supply and be done with it. Only if this is a product to be made many times over would I consider alternate solutions. Such as a forward biased diode between the positive 12 volt power supply line and the Arduino w/ a suitable capacitor (perhaps 100uF to 1000uF depending on the Arduino's current demand and the duration the capacitor needs to maintain a voltage (the duration of the high current demand event)).  It doesn't sound like you have an oscilloscope to help pick a suitable value.

Comment: Ok, its right I don't have a oscilloscope, would it do if I just try with a big 1000uF capacitor?

Comment: Is it possible I've fried up my arduino by now? Its giving even more lag even when connected to laptop now

Comment: One clarity needed, that voltage drop which comes, its because of Rush Current?

Comment: You need to make either your word descriptions more precise or you need to draw better diagrams for us to help.  Some people post pictures showing all connections clearly.  Did you remove the Arduino's positive connection to the 12 volt power supply when you connected only the Arduino to the laptop USB port?  And did you keep the Arduino ground connected to both the laptop and the 12 volt power supply?  I don't mean to put you off, but I think the safest option is to buy a bigger power supply and see if your situation improves.

Comment: BTW, many relays have build in diodes, but I'm not sure about solenoids.  Read [this stack exchange question / answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100134/why-is-there-a-diode-connected-in-parallel-to-a-relay-coil) to understand the purpose of this diode.

Comment: I have added my schematic, can you please take a look and let me know all is fine? I don't want to ruin another Arduino. The only difference to my current wiring is that the solenoid switch is on the -ve side while in the schematic its on the +ve side. Also there is only one tactile switch. The diodes are IN4007. I'm using a relay module so I have just added pinouts for it.

Comment: The diodes have been added now based on ur suggestions, they weren't there before

Comment: I added a link to a diode/capacitor option/discussion if the larger power supply does not work.

Comment: Ok thanks...had added the sockets for the relay as I am using a module https://www.electronicscomp.com/1-channel-5v-relay-module-without-optocoupler?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnbmaBhD-ARIsAGTPcfVcln-o_BiNm7Jp_9r5nsP2b0nzm48GdKvnlaBkGC-nYU4-5W0d5OcaAh6wEALw_wcB . Will test it out on the system once I get my replacements for the ruined stuff. If the problem still persists then will try the other way and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Your pump is turning on as soon as the power is turned on because the relay is connected to 5V. Your processor needs to initialize itself and then the display, the pump is up and running. On your laptop the pump was powered from the power supply and the Arduino by the laptop. The arduino was on and up and running when the pump was started. Hope this helps. I will take a SWAG and say this is powered up when the pump is needed and powered down when it is not needed.

Comment: So how do I get it out of bed in time?